# How to meaningful document an actor design

Tags: java, akka, actor, akka-actor

I'm pretty new to akka/actor systems and try to understand code which a colleague has written.
Doing this, I ask myself what kind of documentation would be helpful to get a faster understanding of the implemented "actor system".
As far as i understand so far, you need to understand at least two different perspective of the systems in order to understand it.

- The first is the static "creation hierarchy" which mainly defines the child-parent relationship between actors.
- The second is the dynamic "message/event flow" which mainly defines the exchanged messages between the actors. As a special case this one also includes realised finite state machines.

So, i wonder if there are common best practices on how to document an actor system:

- What kind of views should be documented?
- Are there recommended ways on how to structure the code (for instance reflecting the parent-child relation as package structure)?
- Naming conventions?
- Tools that are able to parse the code and provide some documentation?
- ...

Answer (score 1):

As I'm yet unable to comment, I'd at least like to point you to [akka-viz](https://github.com/lustefaniak/akka-viz) for the purpose of visualization.

I was also wondering recently about the package structure... and if one should somehow depict the actor hierarchy this way. I then went on and applied a DDD view where actors are nothing but services acting on entities. This doesn't put an emphasis on the **implementation detail akka** when trying to understand what the application does. The latter being what the package structure should enable people to do.

Would also be interested in a best practice though if there is one :)